# PL/SQL Programming: Using block labels to differentiate variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have written below line of code and executing it the same from PL/SQL Developer Tool.

I have also created the HR Schema in my Oracle 11g database.

**Code**

```
CREATE TABLE employees2 AS SELECT last_name FROM employees;
<<MAIN>>
DECLARE
last_name VARCHAR2(10) := 'King';
my_last_name VARCHAR2(10) := 'King';
BEGIN

-- Deletes everyone, because both LAST_NAMEs refer to the column
DELETE FROM employees2 WHERE last_name = last_name;
dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows.');
ROLLBACK;

-- OK, column and variable have different names
DELETE FROM employees2 WHERE last_name = my_last_name;
dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows.');
ROLLBACK;

-- OK, block name specifies that 2nd LAST_NAME is a variable
DELETE FROM employees2 WHERE last_name = main.last_name;
dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows.');
ROLLBACK;
END;
/
DROP TABLE employees2;
```

But while executing the first declare statement it throws error as below

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

Please guide me as I am very new to PL/SQL and currently self learning it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the label and running it?

Comment: Not to be snarky but I am not sure I would want to mix the CREATE step with all the other stuff.  Separate DDL out or whatever... Also, no EXCEPTION block?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the PL/SQL Developer lexer or parser.  You can work around it by enclosing the entire block inside another `begin ... end;`.

---

The SQL window works with both SQL and PL/SQL, but the two statement types have different grammars.  The editor window doesn't need a full parser.  But it must know enough about a statement to know when one statement ends and another begins.  There are many ways to start a SQL statement and few ways to start a PL/SQL block.  The code probably uses a classification algorithm like this: "if it starts with `begin` or `end` it's PL/SQL, else it's SQL".  The programmer probably forgot that PL/SQL can begin with a label.  Since the parser thinks it's a SQL statement it stops at the first semicolon.

You can see in the error and highlighting below that it's splitting the statement based on the first semicolon:

[image]

Frank Schmitt's ideas are good, and usually work around these kinds of problems.  But in this case, neither the Command Window nor highlighting the whole expression will fix the problem.

The only work around seems to be to add an extra `begin` and `end` block like this:

```
--Add extra begin/end to work around PL/SQL Developer parser bug.
begin
    <<main>>
    declare
        v_test number := 1;
    begin
        main.v_test := 1;
    end;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, so I guess it's a client problem.

PL/SQL Developer has different kinds of windows - for this kind of query, you should use a "Command window" (which is essentially a SQL/Plus prompt).

If running the whole script doesn't work, try running each statement separately (in a "SQL window", you can select a code block and run only the selection).

Answer (score 0):

This comment is correct.  Use a Command Window, not a SQL window.  You can also use a Test window to exercise the script if you strip out SQL*PLUS stuff like SET SERVEROUTPUT ...
etc.  That permits a kind of debugging, although I can't quite figure out how to put breakpoints in the main script itself - only called objects.

so for a big example that grabs all the materialized views in a schema and recompiles the invalid, refreshes them and schedules them for nightly refresh. Each task is in its own named block.

***Note that the SQL PLUS command line stuff is turned off here for the Test Window,  but does not need to be disabled for a PL/SQL Developer Command Window...:***

```
    */*SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
\* NB - change the log file name in the PDC file*\
--SPOOL "Script_Compile_Refresh_All_KDOT_BLP_MViews-20230327.log"*

--SET ECHO OFF
--SET TERMOUT OFF

--WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE

*/
BEGIN

<<MAIN>>
DECLARE
         
v_MVN1 VARCHAR2(32767);
v_X1 VARCHAR2(32767);
     
BEGIN

     <<COMPILEMVS>>   
      DECLARE
          CURSOR curMVCompileNames IS 
        SELECT umv.MVIEW_NAME     
        FROM ALL_MVIEWS umv
        WHERE umv.owner =  USER
              and UPPER(umv.COMPILE_STATE ) = 'NEEDS_COMPILE';
       BEGIN   
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[Get the MV names where compile state = 'NEEDS_COMPILE']');
          OPEN curMVCompileNames;
          FETCH  curMVCompileNames 
            INTO v_MVN1;
             
             IF NOT (V_MVN1 IS NULL) THEN
               
                 
                  WHILE (curMVCompileNames%FOUND) LOOP
                    BEGIN
                           
                     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[RECOMPILING INVALID MVIEW ]' || v_MVN1 );
                      v_X1 := q'[ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW ]' ||'  ' ||  V_MVN1 || '  ' || q'[ COMPILE]' ||'  ';
                      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[EXECUTING IMMEDIATE>>> ]' ||v_X1);
                      
                      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_X1;
                      
                    EXCEPTION     
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                        BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[COMMAND FAILED ]' || V_X1);
                        CONTINUE;
                        END;        
                    END;
                    
                    FETCH curMVCompileNames
                      INTO v_MVN1;
                  END LOOP;
           END IF;

          CLOSE curMVCompileNames;
         
     END COMPILEMVS;

 
    <<REFRESHMVS>>
      DECLARE
      CURSOR curMVValidNameCSV IS 
      SELECT LISTAGG( umv.MVIEW_NAME , q'[, ]' ) 
      WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY CASE
                    WHEN UPPER(umv.mview_name) = 'MV_LATEST_INSPECTION' THEN
                     '01 - '
                    ELSE
                     CASE
                       WHEN UPPER(umv.mview_name) LIKE 'MV_LATEST%' THEN
                        '02 - ' || UPPER(umv.mview_name)
                       ELSE
                        '03 - ' || UPPER(umv.mview_name)
                     END
                  END) AS VALID_MVIEW_NAMES
      FROM USER_MVIEWS umv
      WHERE umv.owner = USER
            and UPPER(umv.COMPILE_STATE) = 'VALID';
      BEGIN   

        v_MVN1 := '';
          OPEN curMVValidNameCSV;
          FETCH  curMVValidNameCSV 
            INTO v_MVN1;                
               IF NOT (V_MVN1 IS NULL) THEN   
                       BEGIN
                          
                          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[VALID MV Names: ]' || v_MVN1 );
                          /*  -- refresh them all right now */
                          DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(list=> v_MVN1 , purge_option=> 2, atomic_refresh=>  false, parallelism=> 4, method=> 'c?');
                               
                        EXCEPTION     
                          WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                              BEGIN
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[REFRESH COMMAND FAILED for MV LIST: ]' || v_MVN1);
                                RAISE;
                              END;        
                       END;
               END IF;      
          CLOSE curMVValidNameCSV;
      END REFRESHMVS;

   <<SCHEDULEMVS>>
      DECLARE       
          CURSOR curMVValidNames IS 
          SELECT  umv.MVIEW_NAME               
            FROM USER_MVIEWS umv
           WHERE umv.owner = USER
             and UPPER(umv.COMPILE_STATE) = 'VALID'
             ORDER BY 
             CASE WHEN UPPER(umv.mview_name) = 'MV_LATEST_INSPECTION'
             THEN
                   '01 - '
                  ELSE
                   CASE
                     WHEN UPPER(umv.mview_name) LIKE 'MV_LATEST%' THEN
                      '02 - ' || UPPER(umv.mview_name)
                     ELSE
                      '03 - ' || UPPER(umv.mview_name)
                   END
                END;               
        BEGIN              
              V_MVN1 :='';

            OPEN curMVValidNames;
            FETCH  curMVValidNames 
              INTO v_MVN1;
                  
            IF NOT (V_MVN1 IS NULL) THEN     
                      
                WHILE (curMVValidNames%FOUND) LOOP
                    BEGIN                      
                      /*   -- set the schedule to refresh each one on a schedule tomorrow at 3AM and every night thereafter at 3AM   */       
                      v_X1 := q'[ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW ]' ||    V_MVN1 ||  q'[ REFRESH COMPLETE START WITH TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 3/24  NEXT (SYSDATE+1) + 3/24 ]';
                      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[EXECUTING IMMEDIATE >>> ]' ||v_X1); 
                      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_X1;                                   
                      
                    EXCEPTION     
                      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                          BEGIN
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(q'[ALTER COMMAND FAILED: ]' || v_X1);
                            RAISE;
                       END;    
                    END;
                    FETCH curMVValidNames
                        INTO v_MVN1;
              END LOOP;              
         END IF;
            CLOSE curMVValidNames;
      END SCHEDULEMVS;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
END MAIN;
END;

/*/

spool off*/
```